# show time in HH:MM only in this javascript code

Tags: javascript

The following JS shows the time in HH:MM:SS format while I need it to show HH:MM only

```
  setInterval(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.getTime();
    var interval = 5*60*1000;
    var last = t - t % interval;
    var next = last + interval + 10*60000;
    d.setTime(next);
    var time = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    $(".clock").html(time);
  }, 1000);
```

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7z9boag8/

Comment: Check out moment.js: http://momentjs.com/ it is perfect for date formatting.

Comment: Thank you but I need it simple/clean code

Comment: So, you have code you don't understand and you want us to modify it for you? That's not what this site is for.

Comment: What could be cleaner than doing this in one line of code?  `moment().format('hh:mm')`

Comment: @Diodeus I don't want to add extra external libraries..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's getHours() and getMinuets() methods available.

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/0todu2y7/

```
jQuery(function($) {
setInterval(function() {
var d = new Date();
var t = d.getTime();
var interval = 5*60*1000;
var last = t - t % interval;
var nextt = last + interval + 5*60000;
d.setTime(nextt);
var hours = d.getHours();
var min = d.getMinutes();
  $(".clock").html(hours+":"+min);
  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var time = d.toLocaleTimeString().match(/(\d+:\d+):\d+( \w{2})*/);
var time = time[1] + (time[2] ? time[2] : "");
```

Comment: It replaces the minutes with 00!!

Comment: @mediaroot now it should work

Comment: Thank you but that didn't work. did you try it?

Comment: Ok i was a little quick there ;)
Now it works with both AM/PM and 24h format

Answer (score 0):

i am sorry . i m not edit your code . i just give you another procedure

```
String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function () {
    var sec_num = parseInt(this, 10); // don't forget the second param
    var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
    if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
    if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
    var time    = hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
    return time;
}
```

Second Formula is

```
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

function yourTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    // add a zero in front of numbers<10
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    t = setTimeout(function () {
        startTime()
    }, 500);
}
yourTime();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
setInterval(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.getTime();
    var interval = 5*60*1000;
    var last = t - t % interval;
    var next = last + interval + 10*60000;
    d.setTime(next);
    var time = d.toLocaleTimeString().split(':')
    time.pop()
    time.join(':')
    $(".clock").html(time);
  }, 60000);
```

I don't think that u shuold run tins function every second. U may do it once in minute.